# Remote RIB iLO on Proliant via RIBCL

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, blade-server, ilo

I'm trying to automate a process for our Ops.  The process requires that some windows servers running on blades are shut down, left down for a few hours, the restarted when some other processes complete.  This is done by an op logging on to each blade's iLO web interface to stop and start.
I've been trying to automate this with HP's cpqlocfg program with partial success.  I can issue the GET_POWER, GET_USER_INFO, etc commands but SET_HOST_POWER fails in a specific way. Using the cpqlocfg GET_EVENTLOG command I can see the events XML login and the power comand being issued from the iLO interface but then nothing happens.  Some hints from googling suggest ACPI isn't configured properly but I can't find any hits on how to verify this.
 Am I even using the right command?  There's also a few other options like PRESS_PWR_BUTTON etc.  Problem is I have nowhere to test this, all I can do at the moment is give a script to ops and ask them to try it as 4am on a Sunday when they try the proc.
The shutdown is trivial as I can use the windows "shutdown" command, it's the power on that I need help on.  Anyone done this?
I'd tag this "rib ribcl ilo" but lack the rep points, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely scriptable. I'd use the Windows shutdown interface to handle that portion. The blade startup can be achieved via scripts or SSH to the blade enclosure's Onboard Administrator *or* to the individual hosts' ILO.

Let's assume these are G7 ProLiant systems. You can use the [ILO Scripting Guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02774508/c02774508.pdf) to determine the commands you need for your automated process.

Comment: As per my comments on John's answer I think the shutdown has to be at the OS level.  Just to keep me on my toes the server doesn't have an OS installed.

Comment: What type of blade servers/chassis are these? C7000/C3000? Do you have access to the Onboard Administrator?

Comment: I'll have access at 0400 Sunday :-( when I sit with ops through the process.  BL460C's according to our CMDB.

Comment: That was it.  I'd got too invested in getting to grips with the iLO scripting tool.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If Widows is running on the server, the only way to ensure a clean shutdown is to run shutdown.exe (or an equivalent utility).  All iLO can do is simulate an ACPI power button press, which isn't guaranteed to work (the OS is free to ignore it, which some versions of Windows do under some conditions).  The blade should power itself off after Windows shuts down.  You should be able to use the PRESS_PWR_BUTTON RIBCL command to turn the server back on.

Comment: Thanks.  I since found an unused iLO board waiting to be commisioned and that seems to be part of the problem.  I can see the virtual power light going off but I think you're right and I need to do the shutdown via windows shutdown. Been on holiday a week so I'll try this Monday.

Comment: Thanks.  I've written a new script for the shutdown that uses WMI and Opsys.Win32Shutdown(1) which works on the 1 server (non-iLO) that I can shut down without being imvited to enhance my CV with added employer diversity ;-)